# Is there an Orthodox Buddhism?

Tags: sects

[Orthodoxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodoxy) in Christianity is the holding to the oldest beliefs.  It is of course impossible for the religion not to evolve at all as new questions and there answer have to addressed. The "Orthodox" version is often considered to be the least evolved sect of a religion.  Does the concept of Orthodox apply in Buddhism?

Comment: Yes. The Mahavihara tradition claims it is the Orthodox while some are reluctant to accept. It is natural for both sides.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, Theravada is often argued to hew most closely to the original teachings of the Buddha. See, e.g. ["Two Main Schools of Buddhism"](http://www.budsas.org/ebud/whatbudbeliev/59.htm) for a very brief overview of this.

As I understand it, this has much to do with the fact that Theravada is the oldest of the extant Buddhist schools of thought, predating Mahayana by a few centuries. Theravada practice is also more localized to geographic regions nearer the birthplace of Buddhism (that is, Sri Lanka and Southeast Asia), and never strayed far from it; this is thought to have contributed to the "orthodoxy" of the school - it mixed less with other intellectual and spiritual traditions.

Additionally, Theravada Buddhists draw primarily on the Pali Canon (the Tripitaka), whereas Mahayana Buddhists draw primarily on Chinese sources. These Chinese sources are relatively more distant from the original teachings of the Buddha in terms of both time and language. As a byproduct of this, the Pali texts are often more "authentic".<sup>1</sup>

That said, the term "Orthodox" has no specific meaning in the context of Buddhism, i.e. there is no such school as "Orthodox Buddhism". There are only lowercase-o "orthodox schools of Buddhism", and what counts as "orthodox" will probably differ depending on who you ask. I should add that [pre-sectarian Buddhism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-sectarian_Buddhism) is almost definitionally the most "orthodox" school of Buddhist thought. The only problem is that, well, it doesn't exist anymore.

---

<sup>1</sup> See, e.g. Rupert Gethin's *The Foundations of Buddhism*, p. 44: "it is likely that [it] is generally the case [...] that the traditions [the Pali recension] preserves are [...] the oldest and most authentic available to us" (elisions/etc because the original sentence was inverted)

Comment: "Predating Mahayana": There is a tendency to connect Theravada with the ancient Sthaviras that separated from the Mahāsāṃghikas, but that's not *necessarily* true. Theravada is definitely connected with the Mahavihara of Sri Lanka but their doctrine may not necessarily go back to the Sthaviras. Theravada either goes back to 400 BCE with the Sthaviras, or 300 BCE with introduction to Sri Lanka or later as Theravada developed itself and gained ascendency in Sri Lanka in 1200 CE. If so Mahayana might actually be older.

Comment: @CalebPaul are you a Mahayanist?

Comment: @senshin: Why does this not become another Unorthodox view? Or another sect like Theravada, Mahayana? How does Rupert Gethin be the ultimate judiciary in this matter? How does it differ from another Personal Opinion?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Orthodox Buddhism, there is *Traditional Buddhism*. Most modern *traditional* branches of Buddhism *with monkery*, root in some or other ancient school. Theravada is not more Orthodox or ancient than most other *traditional* schools.

Comment: Is this evidence-based or just another speculation?

Answer (score 2):

Orthodox Buddhism would be what we call [Pre-sectarian Buddhism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-sectarian_Buddhism), which does not exist any more, as a tradition or school or sect. Pre-sectarian Buddhism split into the Mahasamgika school and the Sthavira school.

The modern Theravada tradition, is probably the closest modern school to Pre-sectarian Buddhism, in terms of its doctrines. Theravada is based on the Sri Lankan Mahavihara school, which descended from the South Indian Tamraparniya branch of the Vibhajyavada school, which descended from the Sthavira school.

In [this blog post](http://santifm.org/santipada/2010/why-devadatta-was-no-saint/), Ven. Sujato wrote:

> The term *sthavira* (mean­ing ‘el­der’) is the Sanskrit ver­sion of the
> term bet­ter known to­day in its Pali ver­sion *thera*, as in Theravāda,
> the ‘Teaching of the Elders’. The orig­i­nal Sthaviras, how­ever, are
> by no means iden­ti­cal with the mod­ern school called Theravāda.
> Rather, the Sthaviras are the an­ces­tor of a group of re­lated
> schools, one of which is the Theravāda.

To me, the most orthodox teachings of Buddhism are found in the Theravada Sutta Pitaka and the Mahayana Agamas, which are essentially the same thing.

Personally, I don't consider the Theravada Abhidhamma and the later Mahayana Sutras (like the Lotus Sutra or Heart Sutra) to be orthodox.

Comment: How on earth, can Bhikkhu Sujato be considered a valid judge in this matter? What are his qualifications? I heard they were expelled monks from some tradition. If so, it is more suspectable.

Comment: @Blake Ven. Sujato may have been expelled from Ajahn Chah's monastery in Thailand due to his noble role in bhikkhuni ordination. But that casts no doubt on his credentials as a scholar and translator of the Pali Canon and Buddhism in general. Both he and Ajahn Brahm are validly ordained monks in the Tharavada Thai Forest Tradition, later expelled only due to political reasons and not due to parajika offenses. The Abhidhamma as a secondary source coming not from the Buddha himself, is explained by Venerables Bodhi and Analayo in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39471/471).

Answer (score 1):

James Jenkins, those interested,

it's a sign of the [Dhamma-Vinaya](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/bmc1/bmc1.intro_en.html#intro1), the Buddhas teachings, to be very orthodox and it's because his good following disciples stayed by what was taught by him as much as they could remember and recollect, that his "(re)-legion" could be brought till this days and is still alive to be used.

What ever "unorthodox" approaches, often simply copies, are traced, can, for the most, be seen as not of what the Buddha taught and advice, yet he gave a lot of advice to proof such seriously without either to reject or take on it at first place, if unusual practices and teachings are approached and one of this sets of tools to prove is called Great Standards, also found under the link above, among other tools to verify the "orthodoxy" and validity of sayings and usual, mostly alien to the Theras (Elders of the monastic community).

While the practice of lay-followers may change over time, which is surely often also followed by certain disciples and particular communities of monks, of course always lead by certain improper desires, the ways the so called "Savaka Sangha" (community of good following disciples of Bhikkhus), the way of the Noble Ones didn't really changed, is still, even if hard to trace and find, alive although decaying naturally. Once the (Re)-legion goes astray, there is no much benefit for it, better it could not contribute much for benefit in the world, which is also a reason why this (re)legion would not adapt common desires simply for the sake of existing on or for maintaining ways of merely for the use of just livelihood and entertaining.

Once the "Religion" is or appears no more orthodox it will be no more maintaining a monastic Sangha which is a huge and unexcelled field of merits.

The essay and collection of [That the True Dhamma Might Last a Long Time: Readings Selected by King Asoka](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/asoka_en.html) may give also some impressions of the Dhamma-Vinayas ("Budddhisms") orthodoxy, which is actually, although claimed otherwise, even since the Mahaparinibbana of the Buddha, most compassionate this upholding of orthodoxy.

> [Now at that time](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji_en.html), one Subhadda, who had renounced only in his old age, was seated in the assembly. And he addressed the bhikkhus, saying: "Enough, friends! Do not grieve, do not lament! We are well rid of that great ascetic. Too long, friends, have we been oppressed by his saying: 'This is fitting for you; that is not fitting for you.' Now we shall be able to do as we wish, and what we do not wish, that we shall not do."
>
> But the Venerable Maha Kassapa addressed the bhikkhus, saying: "Enough friends! Do not grieve, do not lament! For has not the Blessed One declared that with all that is dear and beloved there must be change, separation, and severance? Of that which is born, come into being, compounded, and subject to decay, how can one say: 'May it not come to dissolution!'?"

What ever one nourishes, inwardly, outwardly, that will grow and resist for the individual as well as the opposite. It's seldom, very seldom that one gives into Upasnissaya of the Noble Ones, but having done and do so, one does not need to worry to come not near and sooner or later access the Orthodoxy that leads not only to heavens but to final release form all stress and suffering. Good and bad choices are individual ones, yours, which no one could force.

James Jenkins stated in his question: `"It is of course impossible for the religion not to evolve at all as new questions and there answer have to addressed."`, actually it is, was done by the Sublime Buddha, to release a timeless path and teaching, ever-trace and usable for those ready to be tamed.

*(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks or entertainments binding one in this world but as means for an exit from this wheel)*

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as orthodox in Buddhism. But when translating the real meanings of Buddha is changed. And also in Pali canon it's mentioned that, buddha has mentioned dhamma should not be translated to Sanskrit, its believe that reason for saying that is tge true meaning of words are changed when translating. Eg: Lokaya = World (Loka Sutta), And when we add ‘a' infront, which is Aloka it means Light. So when you uproot Loka (world=Five Aggregates of Clinging) you will see the Aloka = Light which is Nivana or Enlightment.
So the meanings of these suttas are built in to words it self (This is Pali and Sinhalese language).
Apart from that ther's no any thing call orthodox.

Comment: translations are difficult even within english.  e.g. greed vs lust vs craving...clinging vs attachment...too much repetitive words

Answer (score 0):

That's a broad question, I think the answer is "yes and no", so I'll try several small answers.

---

The word "Orthodox" has several meanings:

1. The **true** or **correct** teaching, the Right doctrine
2. By extension, and with reverence to the founder of the religion, the **earliest** or **original** doctrine
3. A **conformist** practice, a practitioner who tries to conform to the orthodoxy
4. A school or church which is **named** "orthodox"

Maybe everyone -- Buddhist or not -- wants to seek or have, or will claim to have, #1 ... even if their version may appear to contradict #2, #3, and/or #4.

---

According to Wikipedia, one of the current schools is called "Theravada" (the Way of the Elder Monks) which seems to me (though I may be wrong) to imply "original" or "orthodox".

It says the name derives from  "[Sthavira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sthavira_nik%C4%81ya)" (which I find a bit strange because now there's bias against Sanskrit in favour of Pali, but that's a different topic).

This [Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sthavira_nik%C4%81ya#Origin) implies that schools used to argue (and split) over who was orthodox and who was schismatic.

---

I've seen a modern user (on this site) write that this kind of topic is of interest to scholars and historians, but that "to us, it's just Buddhism".

---

What is in a name, anyway?

There are political parties named "Conservative" or "Socialist" or "Republican", but that's just the name.

There's little difference IMO between the Orthodox and Catholic churches -- mostly a different set of bishops and a distinct geography, i.e. Eastern versus Roman.

So with such large churches having such slight differences, and a schism which didn't happen until 1054 AD, you might feel safe in thinking that at least one of these churches is "orthodox". But then the protestant reformation happens -- people say, "The church is teaching and practising in ways which Jesus would never have agreed to".

And so you get people like [John Fox](https://qfp.quaker.org.uk/passage/19-07/) who don't support the Established church but claim to be (and seen by some to be) closer to the truth (maybe closer to the "spirit" of the doctrine) than is taught from scriptures.

Perhaps there were already differences, between the "Buddhism" that was taught and practised when Gautama Buddha was teaching (in maybe 450 BCE), and "Buddhism" when it became the State religion in about 250 BCE.

---

Buddhist schools today (and historically) put some importance on "lineage" -- who taught your teacher (etc.)?

Many people will see that (i.e. a living teacher) as more important than the history-of-literature considerations

There's also sometimes a question of whether someone has been authorised (by their own teacher or school) to teach.

So that's a bit of both: i.e. traceable historically, and modern.

---

Everyone agrees that the Buddha's doctrine, the Buddha's words -- [Buddhavacana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhavacana) -- are important and good.

So people sometimes disagree about whether something should rightly be considered or classified as "buddhavacana", and have different definitions.

---

The earliest Buddhism was pre-historic (by which I mean "oral history but not written") -- see for example [Early Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Buddhism) and [Pre-sectarian Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-sectarian_Buddhism).

The official or canonical answer to that fact are that "[Buddhist councils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_councils)" were convened and they decided what's what, and we accept that.

Even so there are scholars and practitioners who think that on at least a few points it's likely that the current doctrine isn't or can't have been "original" (see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3336/254) for one example).

---

Part of the monastic code is that you shouldn't cause a schism in the sangha (which I guess inclines toward orthodoxy).

There's some emphasis in the doctrine though about what "knowing for yourself to be true", so it's not maybe meant to be a slavish adherence to nonsense -- not "conformism above all else".

---

The above all seems quite pedantic. I think there are entire countries which get on  without bothering which such trifles -- [for example](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/27158/buddhism-type-by-country/27160#27160):

> Followers in Vietnam practice differing traditions without any problem or sense of contradiction. Few Vietnamese Buddhists would identify themselves as a particular kind of Buddhism, as a Christian might identify him or herself by a denomination, for example.
>
> The overall doctrinal position of Vietnamese Buddhism is the inclusive system of Tiantai, with the higher metaphysics informed by the Huayan school (Vietnamese: Hoa Nghiêm); however, the orientation of Vietnamese Buddhism is syncretic without making such distinctions. Therefore, modern practice of Vietnamese Buddhism can be very eclectic, including elements from Thiền (Chan Buddhism), Thiên Thai (Tiantai), Tịnh độ Pure Land Buddhism, and popular practices from Vajrayana.

---

Perhaps there are some differences but they're not a big deal, not worth fussing about. Or maybe it can be said that the schools have [a lot in common](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1487/254).

---

It may be that questions of "orthodoxy" are a type of conceit -- "I am orthodox, we are orthodox, you are not orthodox".

I say conceit because, to me, "orthodox" implies a comparison (i.e. compared with unorthodox or non-orthodox), and [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/9424/254) implies that comparisons derive from conceit.

We are also warned that conceit and so on, maybe attachment to views, lead to sectarian arguments.

---

In practice I think that, for some people, their view of Buddhism overlaps with nationalism ("our country has the best, perhaps the most orthodox, form of Buddhism") or sense of national identity.

I guess that's human, as far as it goes, unless it becomes inhumane.

---

The vinaya (the monastic code) changes little or not at all. There's a story associated with one of the suttas, that at parinibbana the Buddha said he'd allow the monks to change any minor monastic rules, and they never did because they'd never agree on which rules were only "minor".

There are different versions of the vinaya from country to country, but that's an example of an orthodoxy.

In practice there are "monks" who don't try to follow the vinaya in detail.

---

I guess conformance is sometimes judged by an abbot and/or community of monasteries.

A monk who doesn't comply might be excluded from a "lineage" (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajahn_Brahm#Bhikkhuni_ordination) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100112144531/http://forestsangha.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=1&Itemid=8) for an example).

Answer (score 0):

What Lord Buddha Preached can be applied for the past present and future without changing a word or a letter. Lord Buddha never keep a space for us to add anything or delete anything or rewrite any context matching to the current scenarios.  Examples given in Buddhism well matched with all three periods.

But unfortunately in later stages with the different explanations few "Nikaya"[Associations] created among the monks. yet still the Pure Lord Buddha words still prevail with the Thripitaka.

People name them in different ways and some make them as their income sources.  Some name it orthodox buddhism,  some name it new aged buddhism, some name it Mindfulness Buddhism etc.

This is the Mirror buddha gave us to Identify Buddhism.

If any thing that remove kilesa [Defilement] — lobha (passion), dosa (aversion), Moha (delusion) in their various forms, which include such things as greed, malevolence, anger, rancor, hypocrisy, arrogance, envy, miserliness, dishonesty, boastfulness, obstinacy, violence, pride, conceit, intoxication, and complacency and instead improves kusala [Wholesome], skillful, good, meritorious. An action characterized by this moral quality (kusala-kamma) is bound to result (eventually) in happiness and a favorable outcome it is preached by buddha and should be followed.
Also You can apply them to

1. Raga Vinaya - [Raga-vinaya Sutta[The Subduing of Passion]](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.096.than.html)
2. Dosa vinaya - [Pema Sutta-[Affection]](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.200.than.html)
3. Moha Vinaya - [Mula Sutta-[Roots]](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.069.than.html)
4. Chathuraarya sathya - Four Noble Truths
5. Aaryaashthangika Magga - Noble Eight fold Path
6. Patichchasamuppadaya - Dependent origination
   Moha Vinay Sutta is there in Sinhala and Pali but could not find in English Version.

What Lord buddha taught us if anything that matches to above one of the factors just accept and follow if not even some told that lord buddha preached just neglect it.
All these are purifying your mind or consciousness from the defilements and direct to Nibbana. If anything not fulfill the above path neglect them.
Read one's own mind - [Sacitta Sutta: One's Own Mind](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.051.than.html)

There are thousands of sutta to check whether you are in correct path.

May Triple Gem bless You.