# Buddhism type by country

Tags: academic-buddhism

Could someone give me a breakdown of the form of Buddhism likely to be represented by Vietnamese and Cambodian?

We have six Buddhist churches/Organizations near us and I've contacted them but because of a communications barrier I am unable to determine what form three of them are.

There are two Vietnamese called Phuoc Vien & Tu Vien Hong Duc - and another one representing Cambodia just called a Buddhist Society.

Thanks. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia says, [about Vietnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_in_Vietnam):

> Followers in Vietnam practice differing traditions without any problem or sense of contradiction. Few Vietnamese Buddhists would identify themselves as a particular kind of Buddhism, as a Christian might identify him or herself by a denomination, for example.

... and goes on describe aspects of Vietnamese Buddhist practice.

It also says:

> The overall doctrinal position of Vietnamese Buddhism is the inclusive system of **Tiantai**, with the higher metaphysics informed by the Huayan school (Vietnamese: Hoa Nghiêm); however, the orientation of Vietnamese Buddhism is syncretic **without making such distinctions**. Therefore, modern practice of Vietnamese Buddhism can be very eclectic, including elements from Thiền (Chan Buddhism), Thiên Thai (Tiantai), Tịnh độ Pure Land Buddhism, and popular practices from Vajrayana.

... and:

> The central and southern part of present-day Vietnam were originally inhabited by the Chams and the Khmer people, respectively, who followed both a syncretic **Śaiva-Mahayana** (see History of Buddhism in Cambodia) and **Theravada** Buddhism.

And [about Cambodia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Buddhism_in_Cambodia):

> **Theravada** Buddhism is the state religion of Cambodia, which has had been presented since at least the 5th century.

---

[Tu Vien Hong Duc](https://comparisonproject.wp.drake.edu/religions-of-des-moines/tu-vien-hong-duc/) is described as:

> While Tu Vien Hong Duc is therefore best classified as a Pure Land Buddhist temple, it is much more a Vietnamese Buddhist temple.

According to Google Maps, Phuoc Vien and Tu Vien Hong Duc are located in the same building.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wished I would have found the Comparison project link a month ago. Would have saved me a lot of time. :)